# С++ UDP Win -> Linux

Tags: c++, linux, сокет, udp

Я написал 2 простых класса udp(путём нарезания какого-то кода сервера и клиента).

```
#include "usefull.h"
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

class IADDR
{
public:
    sockaddr_in addr;
    IADDR()
    {
        memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
        addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    }
    IADDR(string ip,int16_t port)
    {
        memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
        addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        char buff1[100];

        InetPton(AF_INET, ip.c_str(), &addr.sin_addr.s_addr);
        addr.sin_port = htons(port);
        //addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(addr.sin_addr.s_addr);
    }


};

class UDP
{
public:
    UDP()
    {
        ok = 0;
        if (!is_st)
        {
            WSADATA w;
            int res = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &w);
            if (res != 0)
            {
                return;
            }
            is_st = 1;
        }
    }
    ~UDP()
    {
        if (ok == 1)
        {
            closesocket(sock);
            ok = 0;
        }
    }
    void set(IADDR a)
    {
        if (ok == 1)
        {
            closesocket(sock);
            ok = 0;
        }
        if (is_st == 0)
            return;
        addr = a;

        sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
        u_long nMode = 1;
        if (ioctlsocket(sock, FIONBIO, &nMode) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            closesocket(sock);
        }

        ok = 1;
    }
    void send(vector<byte> v)
    {
        send(&v[0], v.size());
    }
    void send(const byte* buff, uint32_t size)
    {
        if (ok == 0)
            return;
        int len = sizeof(addr.addr);
        sendto(sock, (char*)buff, size, 0, (sockaddr*)&addr.addr, len);
    }
    bool recv(vector<byte> &data)
    {
        if (ok == 0)
            return 0;
        data.resize(1024);

        sockaddr_in serverInfo;

        int fromlen = sizeof(addr.addr);
        uint len = recvfrom(sock, (char*)&data[0], 1024, 0, (sockaddr*)&serverInfo, &fromlen);
        if (len != SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            data.resize(len);
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            data.resize(0);
            return 0;
        }
    }
private:
    int sock;
    IADDR addr;
    int ok;
    static int is_st;
    friend class UDPSERVER;
};


class UDPSERVER
{
public:

    UDPSERVER()
    {
        ok = 0;
        if (!UDP::is_st)
        {
            WSADATA w;
            int res = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &w);
            if (res != 0)
            {
                return;
            }
            UDP::is_st = 1;
        }
    }
    ~UDPSERVER()
    {
        if (ok == 1)
        {
            closesocket(sock);
            ok = 0;
        }
    }
    void set(USHORT port)
    {
        if (UDP::is_st == 0)
            return;
        if (ok == 1)
        {
            closesocket(sock);
            ok = 0;
        }
        struct sockaddr_in sv_ip;
        sv_ip.sin_family = AF_INET;
        sv_ip.sin_port = htons(port);
        sv_ip.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

        sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
        if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            return;
        }

        u_long nMode = 1;
        if (ioctlsocket(sock, FIONBIO, &nMode) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            closesocket(sock);
            return;
        }
        if (bind(sock, (sockaddr*)&sv_ip, sizeof(sv_ip)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            closesocket(sock);
            return;
        }
        ok = 1;
    }
    void send(vector<byte> v, IADDR &a)
    {
        send(&v[0], v.size(), a);
    }
    void send(const byte* buff, uint32_t size, IADDR &a)
    {
        if (ok == 0)
            return;
        int fromlen = sizeof(a.addr);
        sendto(sock, (char*)buff, size, 0, (sockaddr*)&a.addr, fromlen);
    }
    bool recv(vector<byte> &data, IADDR &a)
    {
        if (ok == 0)
            return 0;
        data.resize(1024);


        int fromlen = sizeof(a.addr);
        int len = recvfrom(sock, (char*)&data[0], 1024, 0, (sockaddr*)&a.addr, &fromlen);
        if (len != SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            data.resize(len);
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            data.resize(0);
            return 0;
        }
    }
private:
    SOCKET sock;
    IADDR addr;
    int ok;
};
int UDP::is_st = 0;
```

В сокетах я ничего не понимаю. Работает вроде правильно но не крашнется ли?
И надо бы как-то его на линукс перевести но как? Использование boost не приемлимо!(ибо он 2 часа устанавливается да ещё и не с 1 раза). QT тоже не использовать т.к. у него есть лицензия.

Win компилю VS а линукс QTCreator.

Компилить под линукс даже не пытался т.к.  явно под виндовс.

Comment: Можно поинтересоваться, зачем вам два почти одинаковых класса? Я так понял, один из них - сервер, а второй - клиент. Но 90% кода в обоих классах одинаковы. По поводу перевода на Linux сейчас напишу.

Comment: Затем чтобы попроще работать с сетью. И я просто распилил код на классы не разбираясь что в нём.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для перевода кода на Linux вам потребуется изменить системные вызовы работы с сокетами на POSIX.
Если смотреть по порядку, первый ваш вызов - это преобразование строки, определяющей IPv4 адрес, в структуру адреса через `InetPton`. Ее необходимо заменить на следующее:

```
inet_pton(AF_INET, ip.c_str(), &addr.sin_addr);
```

Функция возвращает 1 в случае успеха.

Вызов `WSAStartup` и все, что с ним связано, на Linux вам не потребуется.

Функцию `closesocket` необходимо заменить на `close`. Параметр - дескриптор сокета `sock`.

Вызов `socket` для создания сокета не изменится, они идентичны в обоих системах. В случае успеха функция вернет неотрицательный дескриптор типа `int`.

Вызов `ioctlsocket` необходимо изменить на следующее:

```
int flags = fcntl(sock, F_GETFL, 0);
fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
```

`fcntl` в случае неудачи возвращает -1. В качестве альтернативы есть и `FIONBIO` вариант, но `O_NONBLOCK` входит в стандарт POSIX и использовать `FIONBIO` я **не советую**:

```
int opt = 1;
ioctl(sock, FIONBIO, &opt);
```

Вызов `sendto` идентичен на обоих системах, как и `recvfrom`. Обе функции возвращают -1 в случае неудачи.

Во всех вызовах соответственно надо переделать проверки на возвращаемые функциями значения. Также в Linux дескриптор сокета имеет тип `int`.

**Примечание**

На вашем месте я бы еще раз подумал об организации структуры вашего кода. Оба ваших класса во многом дублируют друг друга, а в некоторых местах есть неиспользуемые переменные.

Также, как заметил *test123*, вы используете сокет в неблокирующем режиме, соответственно попытки получить данные из сокета когда их там еще нет приведут к ошибке функции `recvfrom`. Если вам действительно нужен неблокирующий режим сокета, вы можете использовать `select` или `pselect` для ожидания входных данных.

Если вы используете `Qt`, то у него также есть свой вариант работы с сокетами через класс `QUdpSocket`. Его описание есть в [официальной документации](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qudpsocket.html).

Comment: + для ожидания во время чтения входящих данных, если не ошибаюсь, можно применять select, он так же соответствует POSIX

Comment: @test123, совершенно верно. Но, судя по коду ТС, он не ожидает входящих данных. Хотя это и странно. Пожалуй, добавлю `select` в примечание.

Comment: У автора в корне неверная архитектура. Достаточно создать универсальный интерфейс с публичными методами. Как пример, один из моих велосипедов: https://pastebin.com/AtrBnULn Говорю сразу, в нём так же есть свои извращения... Далее, хидер можно использовать на любой ОС. Останется только добавлять новые ОСи файлики реализаций для них.

Comment: А что с инклудами делать? Или в линуксе сокеты встроены в с++?